# Incrementing index in inner loop and update index for outer loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I change the index of the 2d list while appending data in the inner loop and update the index after iteration is complete for the outermost loop?

```
item_list =['data1','data2','data3','data4','data1', 'data6','data7','data9','data10','data11','data12']

item_list_2 = ['data1','data2','data3','data4']

item_list_3 = ['data1','data2','data3','data3','data5','data3','data7','data8','data9','data3','data11','data12']
Data_table_array = []
for index, items in enumerate(item_list):
  if items == 'data1':
    for item2 in item_list_2:
        Data_table_array[index].append(item2)
    for item3 in item_list_3:
       if item3 == 'data3':
         Data_table_array[index].append(item3)
```

expected OutPut

```
Data_table_array = ['data1','data2','data3','data4','data1','data2','data3','data4','data3']
```

for inner loop index remain the same it only changes when the loop goes to the outer loop. as inner loop has different condition i want to indent index if condition trues but actually compiler is appending the data on same index becasue index doesnt changes

Comment: Please paste the code directly from the editor

Comment: consider removing single inverted commas from every line and post it again.

Comment: I think it would be very helpful (notwithstanding previous comments) if you could show a sample of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing this:

1. Store a variable with the latest updated index you want
2. When the next iteration happens in the outer loop, check if the index of the loop matches the stored variable.

For example:

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
latest_index = ''
checker = True
    
for i, elem in enumerate(foo):
    if elem == latest_index:
        checker = True
    if checker:
        print(elem)
        if i < len(foo) - 1:
            latest_index = foo[i+1]
        checker = False
```